# GET Index Schema from Azure Search

Tags: azure, indexing, lucene, database-schema, azure-cognitive-search

I'm currently working on a POC that uses Azure Search to make an Angular Front End.

I've searched everywhere and am looking for a way to query for the index schema.

What do I mean by this?  On [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798941.aspx) you can use a PUT to create an index using JSON.

Is there a way to get this JSON schema back using a GET or using the Azure Portal?  I want to be able to populate a NavBar with the facetable fields without having to hard code them.  Is this possible?

Comment: like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798939.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [`Get Index REST API`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798939.aspx) to get the schema of an Index.

Your request URL would be:

```
https://[service name].search.windows.net/indexes/[index name]?api-version=[api-version]
```

You would need `Admin Key` to authenticate the `Get Index` request.

You will need to parse `fields` element from the response body to get the list of all attributes of the index.

Comment: I checked this one because it had a little more effort...they both had about the same time for an answer.  I found this as well and it wasn't working. I realized I had `.../indexes/[index name]/docs?api-version=[api-version]` instead of removing the `/docs` part of the query.  Thank you

Comment: Any suggestions as to how to "parse the fields element from the response body" ?? The returned odata string is not helping...