# Get Index Azure Search Fails 'Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403'

Tags: javascript, azure, cors, azure-cognitive-search

I previously posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37281251/get-index-schema-from-azure-search) on how to pull the index schema from azure search.

I was able to pull an index schema by using the [GET Index REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798939.aspx) using Postman with no problems, but when running my code in a browser I get the error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://[service name].search.windows.net/indexes/[index name]?api-version=[api-version] Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403`

I'm just running the following code in the console:

```js
$.ajax({ url: 'https://[service name].search.windows.net/indexes/[index name]?api-version=[api-version]', type: 'GET', datatype: 'json', headers: {'api-key': [api-key]}})
```

However, this code works fine (returns all data-- the only difference is `/docs`):

```js
$.ajax({ url: 'https://[service name].search.windows.net/indexes/[index name]/docs?api-version=[api-version]', type: 'GET', datatype: 'json', headers: {'api-key': [api-key]}})
```

The other weird thing is that the request headers for the GET Index Request doesn't show the API key.

It seems like CORS (which is setup on Azure Search to '*'), doesn't like the request from a browser for the GET Index?

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax - POST from Localhost Generates No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37127195/jquery-ajax-post-from-localhost-generates-no-access-control-allow-origin-hea)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Search does not support admin-level operations like Get Index in CORS requests. See [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37127195/jquery-ajax-post-from-localhost-generates-no-access-control-allow-origin-hea/37144906#37144906).

Comment: Thank you...That was what I was looking for.